# Isolating two WireGuard subnets

Tags: iptables

On an AWS server I am hosting a WireGuard peer with two WireGuard interfaces:

- wg0 - 10.0.1.0/24
- wg1 - 10.0.2.0/24

There are two groups of clients connecting to the same AWS server but with different target WireGuard interfaces. At the moment, a PC connecting to wg0 can ping a client on the subnet of wg1 10.0.2.0/24.

I would like to block any access in between the two subnets, such that any client connecting to wg0 will not talk to clients on wg1.

I tried to add iptables rules and have the below

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wg1 -o wg0 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i wg0 -o wg1 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.1.0/24 -d 10.0.2.0/24 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.2.0/24 -d 10.0.1.0/24 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i wg1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
```

However, I can still ping from a client on wg0 the clients on wg1 with the above. What may be also needed to implement the block?

I tried to disable net.ipv4.ip_forward, but the access was still possible.

Comment: What do you have in "nat" and "mangle" tables ?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake and the above is indeed working. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just want to update that the above lines are actually working. and I was only not noticing it, as I forgot to setup routing on my PC to 10.0.2.0/.24 to begin with. If routing wasn't set, somehow pinging form 10.0.1.8 (my PC) to many address in 10.0.2.0/24 will not result in packet loss even there isn't a client at that 10.0.2.0/24 address.

Then I tested by actually making sure the routing between 10.0.1.0/24 and 10.0.2.0/24 is working with my PC and a minecraft server, setting the above indeed then blocked it.